# CSS Issue - Text on Navigation is Overlapping

Tags: css, navigation

Here is the link of the website im working on **67.23.238.162/~agranexc/agranex_cms/index.php**

Go to the **Navigation > Solutions > Industries**

You will see that the 3rd level dropdown is having a problem. How do I fix that?

**Pls help me**. Thanks

P.S. The text should adjust to the element. So it the list-item has 150px width, long text will adjust.

Comment: there is no problem other than your text is too long ?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried adding this in your CSS:

```
#menu ul li ul li a {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px !important; 
}
```

Your text is too long, as u said, and it's getting the 155px u set before...

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu ul li ul li {
    background: none;
    clear: both;
    display: block !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto !important;
```

remove `overflow: hidden` from above. style.css line no 171

and yes give it some width so background can adjust accordingly

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Actually the overflow hidden is not really there. Its just a product of my experiment. I re-uploaded by css. Check and see. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hi now remove some css as like this

```
#menu ul li ul li{
overflow:hidden; // remove this line
}
#menu li:last-child ul{
right:0 !important; // remove this line 
}
```

Comment: Hi! thankyou for your help. Actually overflow:hidden is not really there. Its a product of my experiments. The right:0 is need for the last dropdown.